# Javascript Subtract Set Date by Todays Date Within Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

currently I have an array that is pulling a future date, and I'm trying to do the "future date" - "todays date" within an array to get a number. The format that the future date is currently being outputted as is below.

```
2021-06-21T16:23:26.182Z
```

I was wondering how I could trim the date when it's being pulled within an array, and then subtract the future date from todays date, to give a number output.

Currently within the array the future date property is being pulled as shown below.

```
futureDate: machine.future.date
```

Would I just do the "split" function on the date to trim it down to 2021-06-21? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Parse the date & set the hours minutes seconds

Answer (score 2):

```
var futuredate="2021-06-21T16:23:26.182Z";
var dif = new Date(futuredate).setHours(0,0,0,0) - new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
// dif is in milliseconds
// days difference = dif / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24
// years difference = dif / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365
```

To address your comment, you can map one array to another - getting the diff value along the way, like:

```
var arr = ["2021-06-21T16:23:26.182Z", "2021-06-22T16:23:26.182Z"];
var difarr = arr.map(futuredate => { 
  return (new Date(futuredate).setHours(0,0,0,0) - new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 ; 
})
//difarr is an array of the difference in days (in this example)
```

Comment: This doesn't account for @OPs requirement that the time be trimmed

Comment: I missed that first time round - updated answer

Comment: After I compare the dates to get the days remaining, can this be done within the array when it's being creating? Or should I be looping through and changing the future date after the array has been created?

Comment: @MelonMan- I updated my answer, does that answer your question?